# Magento Shipping Address being sent in binary values

Tags: magento, paypal, binary, magento-1.6

We’re recently having an issue with some of our customers shipping addresses being sent in binary values for both Magento and PayPal.

Here is an example:

```
Shipping Address
100100101010100011100101010010101101 100100101010100011100101010010101101
100100101010100011100101010010101101
100100101010100011100101010010101101
100100101010100011100101010010101101, 100100101010100011100101010010101101, 100100101010100011100101010010101101
United States
T: 100100101010100011100101010010101101
F: 100100101010100011100101010010101101
```

I contacted PayPal and sent them my API requests. They concluded that the issue is with Magento and not with PayPal. They can’t help me if it’s a Magento issue… So I’m reaching out to you guys, If anyone can help me please don’t hesitate to post a reply.

Thank you!